# Speed of Split Database vs ODBC with SQL Server vs ODBC with Azure Cloud

Tags: sql-server, performance, ms-access

I would like to be able to host my data either in the cloud or in SQL Server, as having all my data in one Access file just doesn't seem the most secure to me (or am I wrong?).

My forms contain many subforms (7 to 30), and it takes only a few seconds to load them all with a split Access database. When my tables are linked to SQL, it takes 5 times as long to load the queries; and when they're linked to the Azure Cloud, any query that pulls from multiple tables takes an unbearable amount of time to load (on the order of minutes).

My question is: is this normal? Is keeping it as a split Access database really the only way to maintain good performance? Clearly the Azure Cloud is not an acceptable place to pull data from, but I was under the impression that SQL Server should be nearly as fast...

edit: Here are some details about my setup.

The query that is taking a while to process is qryTask (which retrieves about 2500 records). Its SQL code is below (even if I remove the ORDER BY line and calculated fields, it's still slow. So I think it has to do with the fact that there are multiple tables involved because another query that has only one table is fast).

```
SELECT tblTask.JobNum, tblTask.Sequence, tblTask.SuperintendentID, tblJob.Closed, tblTask.Approved, tblJob.Revenue, tblJob.Notes, tblJob.Certified, tblEstimator.SortID, tblDivision.SortID, tblTask.Complete, tblTask.Ordering, tblTask.NumOfLaborers, tblDivision.Division, tblSuperintendent.SortID, tblJob.EstimatorID, tblTask.DivisionID, tblJob.JobSiteName, tblJob.JobSiteStreet, tblJob.JobSiteCity, tblTask.ID, tblJob.Customer, tblTask.Item, tblTask.ItemDescription, tblTask.StartDate, tblTask.EndDate, tblTask.WeekendWork, tblEstimator.EstimatorNum & '-' & tblEstimator.FirstName & ' ' & tblEstimator.LastName & '\20' & Mid(tbltask.JobNum,3,2) & ' JOBS\' AS JobMidFilePath, 'TaskID:' & tblTask.ID & ' JobNum:' & tblTask.JobNum & ' DivisionID:' & tblTask.DivisionID & ' Item:' & tblTask.Item AS AuditInfo, tblSuperintendent.FirstName & ' ' & tblSuperintendent.LastName AS SuperintendentName
FROM tblSuperintendent RIGHT JOIN ((tblEstimator RIGHT JOIN tblJob ON tblEstimator.ID = tblJob.EstimatorID) RIGHT JOIN (tblDivision RIGHT JOIN tblTask ON tblDivision.ID = tblTask.DivisionID) ON tblJob.JobNum = tblTask.JobNum) ON tblSuperintendent.ID = tblTask.SuperintendentID
ORDER BY Switch(tblTask.JobNum='***FULL***',0,tblTask.JobNum<>'***FULL***',1), tblDivision.SortID, tblSuperintendent.SortID, Nz(tblTask.[Ordering],99999999), tblTask.JobNum, tblTask.Sequence;
```

Here is the diagram for the query:
[image]

And here is some sample data from the query:
[image]

Comment: Is your backend database on the same machine as the front-end?

Comment: No, the back-end is hosted on a server in the company network. The SQL Server is in a different server in the company network. So neither are in the same machine as the front-end.

Comment: Is this normal? No. You have severe SQL Server performance issues, certainly you are missing the required indexes in the database. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/)

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by missing required indexes? I am a bit confused by the link.. All my tables have a primary key, if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: Can you post some sample tables, data, and queries?  That would help us help you.

Comment: I added some more details in my post